# How to run a ton of scripts in global context?

Tags: webpack

I *think* I've got most of my 3rd party libraries working without using [script-loader](https://github.com/webpack/script-loader), but none of legacy scripts will work. They're all written like,

```
var i_am_totally_global = 6;

function i_expect_to_just_run_in_the_browser() {}
```

So the only option I can think of is to just run them in the global/window context. However, if I try to create an "entry" script with something like this,

```
require('script!./AjaxList');
require('script!./MozCompatibility');
require('script!./DynamicSelect');
require('script!./DynamicSelect2');
require('script!./prototype');
...
```

Then `ProvidePlugin` won't work on them, which means they can't access my vendor libs unless I `script!` those too, but then I'm back to square one -- everything global and webpack does nothing for me.

Isn't there a way to [export](https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html#exporting) everything that was declared in the global scope, without explicitly listing out each and every single function + var?

---

I found another loader, [legacy-loader](https://github.com/peerigon/legacy-loader), which I thought would do what I wanted. However, it can only export globals that have been added to the window object, either explicitly (`window.abc = xyz`) or implicitly (`abc = xyz`). If, however, your legacy script does `var abc = xyz` or `function abc() {}` it won't work because if you wrap that in a function, then those become local vars which are pretty much impossible to access in JavaScript.

The only real way to do it AFAIK is to actually *parse* the JavaScript. However, Webpack is already parsing the JS so you'd hope that it could gather up these top-level local vars, but there doesn't appear to be an option for that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like [Expose Loader?](https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader) would allow you to do this?

Comment: Not unless Expose has a secret "expose all the things" option that I'm unaware of.